# add content to div in site.master

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I have a `div` in a site.master file `id="editbtn" runat="server"` and I am trying to add content to it from one of the pages that use the site.master.

I've stried this

```
  ContentPlaceHolder edit = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("editbtn");
```

but as you can gues it doesn't work.

any clues anybody

Comment: A `div` is not a ContentPlaceHolder.

Comment: You are trying cast a div to ContentPlaceHolder. which is wrong

Comment: Which part of this fails?  Does `Master.FindControl("editbtn")` not find anything?  Or does it find something that can't be cast to a `ContentPlaceHolder`?  Debug this and see.

Comment: I would say that using jQuery html/append methods can be options to add some content

Comment: @PiotrCzarnecki: And you would be wrong as long as we're talking about server-side code.

Comment: -1 poor question, lack of effort.  Read up on some fundamentals, this isn't a tutorial site.

Comment: thats as far as I have got when on the next line i try edit.innerHtml the innerHtml isnt there.

Comment: @andrewslaughter: What *is* there?  In what way does this fail?  Be specific.  What is the type of `edit`?  `.innerHtml` sounds like a JavaScript property, not a property on a C# object.

Comment: @David yes of course you're right I forgot to add that this is client side option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `div` should be cast as an `HtmlGenericControl`:

```
HtmlGenericControl d = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("editbtn");
d.InnerHtml = "Success!";
```

So that should fix your problem... doesn't mean this is the best way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: MikeSmithDev solution properly answers your question, but you should really get a basic understanding on the concept of master pages. Start by reading this articles: - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333650/Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET